# Changing error logging in Spring Boot/Netty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, netty

I have a Spring Boot application that is running Netty for a REST API.

I have a WebExceptionHandler to handle exceptions that may occur, which is working. It builds appropriate responses and sends them.

The problem is, it also still logs the exception as an error. I want to change this to log it as an info instead (because we have tracking and alerts that operate differently based on info or error). It even logs things like 404's as errors.

It seems like [`exceptionCaught` in a `ChannelInboundHandler`](https://www.baeldung.com/netty-exception-handling) would help, but `exceptionCaught` is deprecated. I can't find anything that doesn't use this method, and I can't find anything referring to what (if anything) has replaced it).

I also tried using an `@ControllerAdvice` or `@RestControllerAdvice` with an `@ExceptionHandler`, but that is never called.

What is the correct way to intercept and handle the logging of the exception?

---

A minimal example implementation of our current set-up looks like this:

```
@RestController
class MyController {
  @RequestMapping(method = [GET], value = ["endpoint"], produces = [APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
  fun myEndpoint(): Mono<MyResponse> = createResponse()
}

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
class MyWebExceptionHandler : WebExceptionHandler {
  // This does get called and sends the appropriate response back, but an error is logged somewhere outside of our code.
  override fun handle(exchange: ServerWebExchange, ex: Throwable): Mono<Void> = 
    createErrorResponse();
}

// Tried using both, or just one at a time, no difference.
// It does get created.
@ControllerAdvice
@RestControllerAdvice
class MyExceptionHandler {
  // Never called
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception::class)
  fun handle(ex: Exception) {
    log.error(ex.message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

More information on how you are implementing your Exception Handler would be helpful.
here's a simple implementation which i follow to convert the exceptions and log them.

```
 @ControllerAdvice 
public class DefaultExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultExceptionHandler.class);
    private static String ERROR = "ERROR";

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> exception(Exception e) {
        Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>(1);
        Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>(1);
        m.put("message",e.getMessage());
        map.put(ERROR, m);
        LOG.info("some error " + e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Also don't forget to create a bean or add you ExceptionHandler class to the spring config.

```
@Bean
public DefaultExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler(){
    return new DefaultExceptionHandler();
}
```

Comment: This is what I have tried, and unfortunately it never goes into their. It looks like I don't have `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` because our version isn't that up-to-date. However, I've added the rest of the exception handler logic and it never gets called. Our `WebExceptionHandler` for handling sending the error response (which works properly), but something else is doing the logging, which is what I'm trying to intercept.

Comment: @samanime will it be possible to share your ExceptionHandler implementation, so that i can try to reproduce it or better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated my question with what should be a minimal implementation of the relevant bits we have. Please let me know if you need any more. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you wired MyExceptionHandler class to spring config. if not can you try adding @Component to MyExceptionHandler class, i think it's not wired correctly.